# How to record user pressing UIbutton sequence in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to make a series of numbers on different UIbutton e.g 1-10 with ten buttons.

I want to record the sequence that user pressed e.g. "198768" then when the users finished and press the finish button, the sequence of 198768 shows up with an alert view. It is not necessary to save the sequence but just to show up in the alert view.

How can i do that?

thanks

Comment: How about assigning a tag to every UIButton, then on its action take the tag value, and store it in a NSMutableArray as NSNumber. When the user presses the finish button, you simply read the numbers one by one and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks it sounds good, but as a beginner, i am not too sure how this can be done. How to use array and read the array. I will look for it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Clarence I got an Answer for your Question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to record user pressing UI-button sequence in Xcode:

Step 1: In Mainstoryboard or Xib create 11 buttons with whatever numbers you want and one button to get your results plus an textfield.

Step 2: In ViewController.h write this Code:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  Test4
//
//  Created by Stackoverflow on 1/06/12.
//


@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *display;
    IBOutlet UIButton *cbutton;
    NSString *storage;

}
- (IBAction) button1;
- (IBAction) button2;
- (IBAction) button3;
- (IBAction) button4;
- (IBAction) button5;
- (IBAction) button6;
- (IBAction) button7;
- (IBAction) button9;
- (IBAction) button10;
- (IBAction) finalbutton; 

@end
```

Step 3: In ViewController.m write this code:

```
        - (IBAction) button1 {
            display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@1",display.text];
        }
        - (IBAction) button2 {
            display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@2",display.text];
        }
        - (IBAction) button3 {
            display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@3",display.text];
        }
        - (IBAction) button4 {
            display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@4",display.text];
        }
        - (IBAction) button5 {
            display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@5",display.text];
        }
        - (IBAction) button6 {
            display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@6",display.text];
        }
        - (IBAction) button7 {
                display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@7",display.text];
            }
            - (IBAction) button8 {
                display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@8",display.text];
            }
            - (IBAction) button9 {
                display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@9",display.text];
            }
            - (IBAction) button0 {
                display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0",display.text];
            }
            - (IBAction) finalbutton {



NSString *string = self.display.text;

             UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Final Result"
                                                                  message:string 
                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [message show];

        }

        @end
```

So what the code is doing is when you click on any button (1-10) it will displaye it on a textfield. Then the alert picks up whatevers is in the textfield. Tell me if their is any issue :)

Comment: Thanks. It is useful. However, no matter what button i pressed, the alert view shows "Final Result %@,display.text" instead of any numbers.

Comment: Again... "Final Result %@,display.text"

Comment: I forget to add the NSString which should remove the Errors :)

Comment: Now try the code I have added this line: NSString *NumberMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",display.text];

Comment: The code should now work....

Comment: But now it says "Final Result" (null) even i pressed those buttons

Comment: Did you click the numbers 1-10....

Comment: Yes i did, i tried to click the buttons

Comment: The textfield (name is
display) has values right :)

Comment: Soory now try the new code forgot to add an period..

Comment: @Clarence Did you try the new code :)

Comment: No...still not working..the self.display.text is in red it ask to change to "->"